# Put even lines behind odd lines? Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a hard time with this and was wondering if anyone can help,  This is the output of a python regex search, but I need to change the output but am unsure how?

Output looks like:

```
Tony1
, 7684 dogs
Garry 2
, 8473 dogs
sara111
, 0 dogs
```

I need it to look like:

```
Tony1 , 7684 dogs
Garry 2 , 8473 dogs
sara111 , 0 dogs
```

Basicly taking everyting in the "even" lines and add them to the end of the odd lines?

Is this possible?

Comment: So where is your code and raw data ?

Comment: break the lines into odd and even lines using slices (odd_lines = lines[1::2], even_lines = lines[::2], and then pair them using zip(even_lines,odd_lines)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x="""Tony1
, 7684 dogs
Garry 2
, 8473 dogs
sara111
, 0 dogs"""
print re.sub(r"\n([^\n]+(?:\n|$))",r" \1",x)
```

Regex:`\n([^\n]+(?:\n|$))`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/5

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple using regex.

Find:    `'\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n|\z))'`
Replace: `' $1'`
Flags:   `Global`

Regex details:

```
 \r? \n                        # Even linebreak
 (                             # (1 start), Replacement
      .*                            # All non-linebreak chars
      (?:
           \r? \n                        # Odd linebreak
        |                              # or,
           \z                            # End of string
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
```